# mysql query question about removing data from columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause, sql-delete

```
Select * from setup_module;
+------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+
| module                                   | schema_version | data_version |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+
| Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch                | 1.0.1          | 1.0.1        |
| Amasty_Acart                             | 1.8.0          | 1.8.0        |
| Amasty_Base                              | 1.6.3          | 1.6.3        |
| Amasty_CronScheduleList                  | 1.0.0          | 1.0.0
```

This is what the table looks like right.
I only want to delete the data in the two columns on the right. So let's say i want to delete the first row Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch columns on the right.

I'm sorry i'm horrible in mysql.

```
Delete schema_version from setup_module WHERE module = "Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch";
Delete data_version from setup_module WHERE module = "Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch";
```

Would this be the right syntax? How can i combine as well?

Comment: You are looking for an `UPDATE` query, not `DELETE`. `UPDATE` will change the values in a row, but `DELETE` will remove the whole row.

Comment: Everything else looks right? Just use UPDATE?

Comment: What would the result set look like afterwards?

Comment: Just empty... and then when i rerun the upgrade it would populate new values.

Comment: I just want them blank so new values can be entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Strawberry, it looks like you want an `update` statement rather than `delete`. The syntax would be:

```
update setup_module
set schema_version = null, data_version = null
where module = 'Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch'
```

This resets columns `schema_version` and `data_version` to `null` on the row(s) whose `module` is equal to `'Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch'`.

On the other hand, if you want to delete the entire row(s), then:

```
delete from setup_module where module = 'Aheadworks_AdvancedSearch';
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. Is Null equivalent to blank or will it say Null in the cell? I'd prefer to update but just have the cells blank. @GMB

Comment: @Supplement: `null` basically stands for "no value", or "undefined value". This seems like a reasonable interpretation of what you asked for.

Comment: @Supplement, an alternative to null is just two single quotes `''` Its not the same thing as null but accomplishes your goal of it displaying as empty

Comment: Thank you again for the information. If i just put "" < like this without null would the cells just populate blank?

Comment: @Supplement: yes, you can also assign an empty string (`''`) rather than `null`.